# How to test the function in function component by jest

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs

I am trying to test the function in React component.

My simple component.

```
const TestFunction = (props) =>{
    const testFunc = () => {
        console.log("test");
        return "test";
    };
    return (<div>test</div>)
}
export default TestFunction
```

and test script is like this below

```
import renderer from 'react-test-renderer';
import TestFunction from './TestFunction';
import {render, fireEvent, waitFor, screen} from '@testing-library/react'
import '@testing-library/jest-dom'

    it('check the TestFunction', async() => {
      render(<TestFunction/>)
      expect(testFunc()).toBe("test");
    });
```

However it shows error like this.

How can I test the function in function component?

```
$npm run dev
ReferenceError: testFunc is not defined

  14 |
> 15 |   expect(testFunc()).toBe("test");
     |   ^
```

Comment: How do you expect the `testFunc()` to be accessible from outside the `TestFunction` component, extract it outside.

Comment: Test the action using this function, not the function itself.

Comment: You should never test the internals, just the component's API.  Your example doesn't make a lot of sense since the function does nothing and is not used. Hard to make a suggestion.

Comment: And sorry, I downvoted the question to encourage you to delete it or rewrite it  since creating a dummy component with an unused dummy function doesn't make much sense. At the very least, use `testFunc` in your component so we can tell you how it can be tested through the component's API.

Comment: Thank you for advice. I understood the basic idea. I will close this, and re-learn about testing.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to assert the value during the rendering of the `TestFunction` component, you need to call the `testFunc` function inside the `TestFunction` component

Comment: There is something wrong with your code I believe, you cannot simply destructure the `testFunc` out of the `TestFunction` component. Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: Yes you are correct. By looking at the test, we are trying to assert the value of the `testFunc` when the component is rendered. So this should be fixed first.

Comment: Thank you I understood the basic idea inner function should be called from inside.

Comment: This should be a comment suggestion, not an answer.